# APPEND STARTING NUMBERS

Tags: notepad++

I would like to append a 256 digits to  thousands of number in notepad plus to appear as below:

```
776333533
774361221
772333707
771615215
784713890
786164089
777664662
```

I would want all these numbers to appear as below:

```
256776333533
256774361221
256772333707
256771615215
256784713890
256786164089
256777664662
```

i need a command that can enable me achieve this

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 0):

Using find-replace in regex mode.

Find what: `([0-9]+)`

Replace with: `256\1`

Comment: THIS DOESNT WORKUsing find-replace in regex mode.

Find what: ([0-9]+)

Replace with: 256\1

Comment: It works fine, I've tested it with your set of numbers. Are you using regex mode in find and replace?

Comment: Kindly looks like ive failed. Help me append these numbers and send me a .txt file to enockzg@gmail.com kindly send me your email so i can send you a list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

enable Multiline Select setting from `Settings > Preferences > Editing> Multi-Editing Settings`

Then use `CTRL + Mouse click` to select multi place and write 256

Ref : https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html